# How to change color for particular month of bottom axis of graph in ExtJs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I plotted graph using extjs 4.1, My requirement is, after certain months i need to change color of label of bottom axis(Month fields) of graph. **I have gone many ways as below, but not able to achieve.** Can anybody tell me how to achieve? Great appreciated. Thank you.

**This Method will change entire label color red from JAN to DEC**

```
 {
                    type: 'Category',
                    position: 'bottom',
                    fields: ['month'],
                    //dashSize: 0,
                    label: { 
                        font: '10px Verdana',
                        fill: 'Red',                            
                    }                        
                }
```

**Below Method is not working**

```
{
                    type: 'Category',
                    position: 'bottom',
                    fields: ['month'],
                    //dashSize: 0,
                    label: { 
                        renderer: function(name, a, b, c,attr) {
                            Ext.apply(name, {
                             fill: 'Red'
                             });
                            Ext.apply(a, {
                                fill: 'Red'
                            });
                            Ext.apply(b, {
                                fill: 'Red'
                            });
                            Ext.apply(c, {
                                fill: 'Red'
                            });
                            Ext.apply(attr, {
                                fill: 'Red'
                            });
                            return name;                                
                        }
                    },
                    renderer: function(sprite, record, attr, index, store) {
                        Ext.apply(attr, {
                            fill: 'Red'
                        });
                        sprite.setAttributes({fill: 'red'}, true);
                        return attr;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

finally. I achieved. here is the solution. i am checking here condition like that we can write switch cases, makes color change of particular month.

```
label: {
                        renderer: function(v) {
                            debugger
                            if(v == 'JAN'){
                                //this.font = "bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif";
                                this.padding = 5;
                                this.fill= 'blue';
                            }
                            else{
                                this.fill= 'black';
                            }
                            return v;
                        }
                    }
```